# LiveDataReactiveStreams to MutableLiveData

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

How can I publish values from LiveDataReactiveStreams to MutableLiveData? I would like to implement two-way data binding to Switch (view) and pass "checked" value from database to MutableLiveData and from UI as well. 
LiveDAtaReactiveStreams returns immutable LiveData only.

```
//ViewModel
public final MutableLiveData<Boolean> switchChecked = new MutableLiveData<>();

LiveData<Boolean> data = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(/* Flowable from DB */); //??


//xml
<Switch
  ...
  android:checked="@={viewModel.switchChecked}"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `MediatorLiveData`

```
//ViewModel
public final MediatorLiveData<Boolean> switchChecked = new MediatorLiveData<>();

public MyViewModel() {
    ...

    switchChecked.addSource(LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(/* Flowable from DB */), value -> {
        switchChecked.setValue(value);
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasted a couple of hours to find a solution and finally you helped me.