# Two-way databinding UI control value to domain layer in android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-livedata, rx-android

So, I'm learning some architecture stuff and I'm trying to stick to a strict domain model where I don't depend on any android components. I'm using rxjava in my domain and I'm trying to have changes in my domain layer show in my UI as well as let changes to the UI update the value in the domain. The UI control I'm using for testing is a seek bar if anyone cares, that's not important though and the method should generalize to any control.

## What I've tried so far

### binding using callbacks

I load the value from the domain when the fragment view is created and then I used `OnSeekBarChangedListener` to update the value in domain when the sliders is adjusted.

*This kind of works, but its not scaleable in the way I need it to be. Also if the domain value is changed after the view is loaded, the UI is not updated*

### Converting domain's BehaviorSubject to LiveData

I used `LiveDataReactiveStreams` to convert the `BehaviorSubject` in domain to a LiveData object in my ViewModel, which I think bind to.

*This works one-way. Unfortunately it seems that its not possible to get `MutableLiveData` from `LiveDataReactiveStreams` which means that two-way binding is not possible. It is unfortunate because this would very much be my preferred method as `LiveData` has some nice lifecycle aware features.*

### Converting domain's BehaviorSubject to MediatorLiveData

as per this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56502849/8108014

*This does allow me to get a `MediatorLiveData` which as far as I can tell does allow two-way binding. However, while the viewmodel's livedata value is updated via the UI, the domain value is not.*

I also tried to observe the `MediatorLiveData` object and update the domain that way whenever changes are made, but that predictably causes a feedback loop where the livedata updates the domain, which then updates the livedata, and so on.

Comment: Guard against duplicate state changes, either in the `MediatorLiveData`, or inline in the live Data `LiveData::distinctUntilChanged` - two-way data binding would usually guard against this before updating a value.  If you wish with Android Studio Artic Fox you can use data binding with `StateFlow` and `MutableStateFlow` - which only reacts on state changes by default.

Comment: To use livedata ton from UI thread you have to use postValue method instead of setValue.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)